# Does C++/WinRT provide mapping from enum symbol to string name?

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm using C++/WinRT.  The projection includes many enums. I find myself building my own table of enum values to string literals. This is not a big deal for enums with only a few defined values, but it's a pain when there are a lot of them.

What I really want is some form of compile-time or run-time reflection that converts an enum value into the string representation of the compile-time name that represents a given enum value.  The code snippet below demonstrates.  How can this be automated?

```
std::wostream& operator<< (
    std::wostream& wout,
    winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::DirectXPixelFormat e)
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.directxpixelformat
    using winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::DirectXPixelFormat;
    switch (e) {
    case DirectXPixelFormat::R8G8B8A8Int:
        wout << L"R8G8B8A8Int";
        break;
    case DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized:
        wout << L"B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized";
        break;
    default:
        // TODO: Many enums cases are missing.
        //   Find a way to compile-time-generate the string values from enum value.
        wout << L"Unknown (" << std::to_wstring(static_cast<int32_t>(e)) << L")";
    }
    return wout;
}
```

I could build something that parses the winrt/*.h files to generate a header containing arrays of string literals, then #include the generated header. There probably exists sample code for doing this type of thing unrelated to C++/WinRT. But maybe C++/WinRT includes metadata in the SDK, which combined with one of the C++/WinRT command line tools, can easily do this for me? If it's there I have not found it.

I did find `ApiInformation` interface from winrt/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.h, as well as explanation of "Version Adaptive Code".  I had hoped that OS COM interface behind `ApiInformation` has way to query a name for an enum value, but I was unable to find an answer there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation

Comment: C++/WinRT is standard C++17, and C++17 doesn't have reflection.

Comment: Understood. But the headers in winrt/ seem to be generated by a tool that Microsoft wrote. That tool has the answer.  If the metadata driving the tool is available, then an easy answer might exist for the enums within winrt/

Comment: The tool is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang - Stringification of enum values is not in the spirit of C++. In practice, stringification is useful only for logging purposes, and discussion with people who have done this suggests that they generally regret it and wish they had logged as plain integers instead. Part of the reason is that it's easier to parse integers on the back-end. (Otherwise, your back-end either needs the reverse parser, or it needs to deal with all the different strings that mean the same thing.)

Comment: ApiInformation will not get you what you want. The purpose of that class is light-up. "If this OS supports DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, I will use it."

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out xlang.
Code which takes action on the enum values will not use the stringified the enum names.  I need to stringify for a diagnostic tool where the consumer of the stringified enum-names will be a human's eyes. The diagnostic tool dumps to stdout the current system state.  Humans understand enum names, not numeric values, especially for a thing like DX pixel format.

Comment: You can also use xlang to go beyond C++/WinRT and parse the metadata where the strings actually reside. If you're building diagnostic tooling that's what I'd recommend.

Comment: @KennyKerr, do you know where one can find "the metadata where the strings actually reside?"  Specifically, metadata for the enums that are in the winrt/ headers.

Comment: There metadata resides in the the winmd files that cppwinrt parses to produce the headers. You'll need to find the winmd with the relevant type information. For example, C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata contains the metadata for the current verison of Windows and the Windows SDK contains the metadata for a specific version of Windows (the latter is preferred). The winmd file itself follows the ECMA 335 spec. You can parse that with the old CLR APIs IMetaDataImport and IMetaDataTables or use the xlang C++ libraries to do it much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx#tostring

```
namespace winrt
{
    hstring to_hstring(StatusEnum status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
        case StatusEnum::Success: return L"Success";
        case StatusEnum::AccessDenied: return L"AccessDenied";
        case StatusEnum::DisabledByPolicy: return L"DisabledByPolicy";
        default: return to_hstring(static_cast<int>(status));
        }
    }
}
```